# save entry information with automatic file name

Tags: python, file, tkinter, save

[image]

How can I automatically put the information in the order no tag in the filename tag?

Comment: Set `initialfile=<order_no>` in `filedialog.asksaveasfilename()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.